# What is integration time in microscopy?

Tags: photons, microscopy, two-level-system

What is the "integration time" in Two-photon excitation microscopy?

Answer (score 3):

Its the parameter input that tells the detector how long to collect light before moving on. It determines the exposure of your detector.

During this time interval the detector signal gets superimposed / added/ integrated, effectively increase the exposure.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: What is the difference between exposure time and integration time in CCD exactly? is there a difference or math relation?

Comment: If you are refering to photography, there I guess its used for a vareity of closely related things. Look [this](https://dictionary.university/Integration%20Time) up. All of these in some sense relate to exposure. If you are referring to [Time Delay Integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_delay_and_integration) in CCDs then I am not the best person to answer. All I can say is in Physics Experimentation, Integration Time in [MCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multichannel_analyzer) always refer to exposure. Just to be sure you might want to look up the user manual of your specific device

Answer (score 1):

In camera based systems the integration time is the amount of time pixels photoelectrons are collected in an 'electron well' before being pushed through an analog to digital converter.

In laser scanning systems you usually use the term 'dwell time' and is the amount of time in which a point detector integrates photoelectrons in a single temporal sample (which corresponds to a single output pixel).

2PE microscopes can be built with either cameras or point detectors.