# Why a mode-locked reduce the integration time in microscopy?

Tags: optics, photons, microscopy, fluorescence

Why a mode-locked (laser) reduce the "integration time" in two-photon fluorescence microscopy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two-photon absorption is a nonlinear process, so the higher you can make the excitation intensity, the more efficient the process becomes. The highest light intensities easily available in an optical lab come from focused mode-locked lasers because all of the light power is bunched up into ultra-short pulses. So during the time of the pulse, the intensity is extremely high, even if the average power is kept relatively low to avoid destroying the organic matter under study. Therefore, the high intensity leads to high two-photon conversion efficiency (again, because two-photon absorption is nonlinear), and you get more fluorescence out. More fluorescence means a shorter integration time in your detector to achieve the same signal-to-noise ratio.

Comment: please define integration time in this process??

Comment: @saman https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/661249/29170

Comment: I'm confused about integration time. More fluorescence means a shorter integration time in detector?? but "integration time" determines the exposure of your detector??

Comment: @saman Yes, just like in a regular camera, the more light you have the less time you need to expose for so the lower your integration time can be.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: @samanamiri I should also point out that the nonlinearity of two-photon absorption (TPA) leading to a dependence of the efficiency on the intensity *is the whole point* of two-photon microscopy. When you focus light, it is most intense within a small region around the focal point, and this fact (combined with TPA’s nonlinearity) leads to better imaging resolution compared to standard, linear microscopy.

Comment: thank you very much